# Windows 8 RDC on dual monitor

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have just got win 8 pro and i have xp -pro pc and I use to connect with mstsc.exe /span  from my win 7 computer. but appears to be win 8 didn't work with mstsc /span. just got on one monitor.

How can I get RDC on dual monitor work on win 8?

I didn't see any option on the new " New Remote Desktop connection" apps downloaded from windows store. any idea...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to say that I have not personally tested this since my Win 8 laptop only has one screen.

If you bring up the old graphical RDP client (not the App Store one), you can select the option to use multiple monitors:

[image: RDP Display Options]

Comment: thanks much for quick response.I did select that but I de-selct and select again wala..it's start working. I don't why..anyways you did remind me a good thing. thanks again.